# How to fix / replace metal strip in corner of the wall (uk)

Tags: drywall, walls

A thin strip of metal has pulled away from the wall and is slowly bent and pulling up further up the wall, What is this strip and how would i go about replacing it and fixing the wall?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a corner strip to keep the edge straight. You can remove it, replace it with a new one, and apply the drywall patch over it.

Comment: Can you add a picture higher up the wall showing the "junction" between where it's attached and where it's come off?

Comment: @FreeMan ive added the second picture showing where it meets back at the wall, it did start off much lower but has been peeling away

Comment: Interesting that it's just a flat piece against one side of the corner. Here in the US, we get "corner bead" that's bent at a 90° angle and completely wraps the corner, hence my request for a different pic. TBH, I don't know if those are used for plastering, but they're definitely used for drywall. I was wondering if the corner had come off and was getting flattened.